# corregir CS0136

Tags: c#

como puedo corregir [CS0136](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0136))

```
if (line.Contains(">"))
                        {
                            string ch = ">";
                            char up = char.Parse(ch);
                            int cell = 0;
                            foreach (char up in line)
                            {
                                cell += 1;
                            }

                            MessageBox.Show(cell.ToString());
                        }
```

deberia hacer un foreach de '>' pero da el error CS0136

Comment: No entiendo, el título dice una cosa y tu código hace otra cosa, ¿podrías redactar mejor el problema por favor? Aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Mi problema es cuando en vez de usar 'u' que si es un carácter alfabético uso '>' que no lo es da un error

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ANONIMO y por que no incluyes el error que te escupe el editor???

Comment: A local variable named 'var' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'var', which is already used in a 'parent or current/child' scope to denote something else (tengo el IDE en ingles perdon)

Comment: Tenes dos veces definida la misma variable! asi no va a compilar nunca....